# Add a Mapper to cache with java api

Tags: java, caching, mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I want to add a Mapper to cache with java api in MyBatis. I try this way and add Mapper's namespace to caches, but the statements of the Mapper still has no cache. is there any way to add Mapper statements into the cache?

```java
...
Cache cache = (new CacheBuilder("package.name.SampleEntity"))
      .implementation(PerpetualCache.class)
      .addDecorator(LruCache.class)
      .clearInterval(null)
      .size(null)
      .readWrite(true)
      .blocking(false)
      .properties(new Properties())
      .build();

sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addCache(cache);
...
```

Comment: I don't think there is a public API for that. Why can't you use `<cache />` or `@CacheNamespace`?

Comment: @ave Because the mapper files are in an external library and I don't have access to its code.

Comment: I see. That usage is not considered in the current design, apparently. I've never used it, but Spring's `@Cacheable` could be a viable alternative.